# Iterate view controllers of navigation controller swift

Tags: for-loop, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I want to iterate through view controllers of navigation controller in swift. For that I wrote a for loop like this

```
for navController in tabBarController?.viewControllers {
     //some process
}
```

`tabBarController` is a `UITabBarController`.
But I am getting error like `'$T4??' does not have a member named 'Generator'`
Whats wrong with the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Optional chaining results in optional array of view controllers. Optional arrays do not conform to those protocols for be iterated with for..in loop. Try:

```
if let viewControllers = tabBarController?.viewControllers {
    for viewController in viewControllers {
        // some process
    } 
}
```

Comment: `for viewController in tabBarController?.viewControllers as [UIViewController] {}` also works.

Comment: @Swipesight it shows error viewController '[UIViewController]?' does not have a member named 'Generator'

Comment: @Swipesight sorry my bad my object was tabController not  tabBarController. tabBarController taking view controllers property I think